# なぜスレッド間の同期にvolatileを使ってはいけない？

Tags: c

C言語で、2つのスレッドを同期するに、下記のようなプログラムを書きました。

```
volatile int hoge = 0;
//...
void fuga1() // スレッド1で動いている
{
    while (1)
    {
        while (hoge == 0) // 値が変わるまで待つ
            sleep(1);
        puts("fuga1!");
        hoge = 0;
    }
}

void fuga2() // スレッド2で動いている
{
    while (1)
    {
        sleep(1000); // 1秒待つ
        hoge = 1;
    }
}
```

このプログラムは特に問題なく動いていて、1秒毎に「fuga1」が出力されています。

しかし、「これは`volatile`の正しい使い方ではない」、「スレッド間の同期に`volatile`を使うな」とは聞いたことあります。具体的になぜなのか、誰か教えていただけますでしょうか。

Answer (score 5):

他の回答でも述べられていますが、`volatile` はコンパイラの最適化の影響避けるためのもので、それ以外の何者でもなく、スレッドの同期をとるために用いるのは適切ではありません。

以下のブログ記事を参照すると、なぜ適切でないのかが理解できると思います。

http://i-saint.hatenablog.com/entry/20101005/1286208402

なお、スレッド間で同期をとりたい場合には、`条件変数（pthread_cond）`を用いるのが適切だと思います。
以下は `pthread_cond` を用いた場合のコードです。

```
int hoge = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
//...
void fuga1() // スレッド1で動いている
{
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while (hoge == 0) // 値が変わるまで待つ
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        hoge = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        puts("fuga1!");
    }
}

void fuga2() // スレッド2で動いている
{
    while (1)
    {
        sleep(1000); // 1秒待つ
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        hoge = 1;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}
```

Comment: 変数`hoge`は正しくpthreadのmutexで保護されていますので、`volatile int hoge`ではなく`int hoge`で十分かと思います。

Comment: `while`の中で変数`hoge`を変更していないので、（あくまでもコンパイラ次第ですが）volatile でないと `hoge == 0`の判定を`while`の外側で行うような最適化が加えられてしまう可能性があるのではないかと思いますが、それは無用な心配でしたでしょうか？

Comment: PThreadsに対応したPOSIX準拠コンパイラでは、そのような誤った最適化を行わないと保証されます。http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yupo5656/20040618/p2 で詳しく説明されています。

Comment: @yohjp なるほど、POSIX準拠であればmutexだけで充分なのですね。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 5):

`volatile`変数によるスレッド間同期は、あらゆる環境（コンパイラ、OS）上で期待通り動作する**保証がなされない**ためです。

質問にあるとおり、特定OS上の特定コンパイラでは期待通り動くこともありますが、`volatile`変数＝スレッド間同期として機能することを保証してくれる標準規格（仕様）は存在しません。例えばC言語の言語仕様でもそのような定義は存在しませんし、C言語のうえにくるPOSIX仕様やOpenMP仕様などでもそういった定義は存在しません。

`volatile`変数の振る舞いについてとりわけ誤解を招いているのが、仕様上の保証が無いにも関わらず、多くの環境では`volatile`変数がスレッド間同期として**機能しているように見える**ことです。しかし、あくまで偶然に期待通り動作したというだけですから、「これはvolatileの正しい使い方ではない」、「スレッド間の同期にvolatileを使うな」に繋がります。

JPCERTの [POS03-C. volatile を同期用プリミティブとして使用しない](https://www.jpcert.or.jp/sc-rules/c-pos03-c.html) も参照ください。また @kazuto さんが参照された記事はC++言語についての言及でしたが、C言語についてもそのまま適用できますので参考にください。

補足：もしx86アーキテクチャ（x86-64含む）上でMicrosoft Visual C++ 2005以降を使われているならば、[VC++の独自仕様拡張](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/12a04hfd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)として`volatile`変数＝スレッド間同期として機能します。ただし、新しいC++11/C11言語仕様の策定にともない、アトミック変数が標準定義されましたので、[この独自拡張を積極的に使用すべきではありません](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/jj204392.aspx)。

Answer (score 3):

`volatile` はあくまでコンパイラの最適化によって変数が消されてしまうのを防ぐもので、スレッドセーフにさせるための機能ではないからだと思います。
つまり、`volatile` でスレッドセーフだと「間違った」解釈をしてはいけない、という理由ではないかと。

Answer (score 3):

volatile変数とマルチスレッドとの関係についての押し問答（前編）
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yohhoy/20121016/p1

こちらのブログも参考になると思いますがvolatileが環境依存で動かなくなると言う問題がある事と最近の環境だと未定義動作として定義されている事が使うなの理由の様です。